# Issue with subsetting data; not picking up observations for one category

Tags: r, excel-2010, spreadsheet, subset

I'm attempting to subset data in R from one column of my spreadsheet into three different categories: Cod, Haddock and Whiting. For some reason however, Haddock is not working and is saying there are no observations for this subset, when in fact there should be 51 - the other two categories are subsetting fine with all observations accounted for. What can be the reasons for this? The spreadsheet appears to be ok, and doesn't seem to contain any obvious problems, but is there something I could be overlooking?

Thanks

edit:

ok, here's part of the data set here...

```
OpCode                 Species      DistanceFromCoast
SA_F1_280714_C4_1   Atlantic cod    583.69
SA_F1_280714_C4_1   Haddock         583.69
SA_F1_280714_C4_1   Whiting         583.69
SA_F1_290714_C2_10  Atlantic cod    892.51
SA_F1_290714_C2_10  Haddock         892.51
SA_F1_290714_C2_10  Whiting         892.51
SA_F1_280714_C4_6   Haddock         1080.5
SA_F1_280714_C4_6   Whiting         1080.5
SA_F1_280714_C4_6   Atlantic cod    1080.5
SA_F1_280714_C4_7   Whiting         1030.59
SA_F1_280714_C4_7   Haddock         1030.59
SA_F1_280714_C4_7   Atlantic cod    1030.59
```

Comment: Some example data would be helpful..

Comment: how are you reading in the files? your `read.table` or `read.csv` statements would help

Comment: Check what exactly is contained the category for Haddock, it's possible that you are checking for "Haddock" when the value in the column is "Haddock " or " Haddock"(not spaces). How exactly are you subsetting the data? Can you give us the code and some sample values?

Comment: Michal, I'm reading files by using the read.csv function

Comment: Colin, the heading for that column is 'species' so there is no overlap between that and the subsets

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something with the `class` of your variables.  Try

```
str(dat)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ OpCode           : Factor w/ 4 levels "SA_F1_280714_C4_1",..: 1 1 1 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ Species          : Factor w/ 3 levels "Atlantic Cod",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 2 3 1 3 ...
 $ DistanceFromCoast: num  584 584 584 893 893 ...
```

A grouping operation should work fine,

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Ave.Dist = mean(DistanceFromCoast))
#        Species Ave.Dist
# 1 Atlantic Cod 896.8225
# 2      Haddock 896.8225
# 3      Whiting 896.8225
```

To graph by group using `ggplot2`, you need to specify a grouping option in `aes` (ie. color, shape, group, etc).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Species, y=DistanceFromCoast, fill=Species)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: Thank you LegalizeIt for the advice (I'd give you an upvote if I had enough rep). Though is it possible to use this function to categorise the three species and make graphs? That's partly what the issue is with this data set